# DNS resolution error when viewing a question

Tags: discussion

I've tried to visit this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177719/javascript-case-insensitive-search?rq=1) an hour ago, but it throws an error:

[image: CloudFlare Error]

And I tried to refresh it a couple of times, but the error won't resolved. I can't even access the home page. So I left the page then. After some time, let say a half hour, it is now fixed, that error screen is gone! I just want to asked what triggers this phenomenon, and what can I do to avoid it (as a programmer, my weakness is Computer Networking).

In case you asked my topographical location, I'm on Philippines.

Comment: `and what can I do to avoid it` There's nothing *you* can do to avoid it, really. It happened because the DNS was improperly configured, or the DNS provider was done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A DNS resolution error typically indicates one of the following things:

- A request for a domain was made to a CloudFlare IP address and that domain does not exist on the CloudFlare network, ie- the domain hasn't been added to a CloudFlare account. As a result, CloudFlare does not know where to route that request.
- The target of the DNS record for the domain requested through CloudFlare does not resolve.
- The record requested is a CNAME record pointing to an external DNS provider that is currently experiencing downtime.